# CopyData, but do not count cells with empty formula in it

Tags: google-sheets

My goal: copydata on button from one sheet to other, only non-blank cells.

Basicly I created simple copy button, but it is counting everything in the spreadsheet. The whole spreadsheet is filled with formula like this one: =IF(B14="";"";Import!$D$2). My goal would be to only copy whole data that if the formula gives false = data and leave the blank formula alone.

My current code is like this:

```
function CopyData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Auto'); // use your sheet name for sheet1
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Test'); // use your sheet name for sheet2
  const rg = sh1.getDataRange()//selects whole data 
  const drg = sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() + 1 , 1);//Select destination range. You only have to specify the upper left corner of the range
  rg.copyTo(drg, {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

I have found somewhere a code like this, but I'm to new to this to be able to aply it to my current code and I'm not sure if it would work.

```
rg.filter(function(row) {return row.filter(String).length > 0});
```

I also found a code that works as my goal would be, but the issue is that it is very slow it checks row after row and I sometimes have to copy for example 300 rows at once. That would simply take to long.

```
function CopyData(CopyData) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName("Auto");
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName("Test");
  var rg1=sh1.getRange("A2:M2000");
  var vA=rg1.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(vA[i][5]){
      sh2.appendRow(vA[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a solution to my issue? If so what should my steps look like to fix it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please share example output where it is still showing the formulas? Upon testing, your code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About `I also found a code that works as my goal would be, but the issue is that it is very slow it checks row after row and I sometimes have to copy for example 300 rows at once.`, in your bottom script, `appendRow` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. [Ref Author: me](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

From `I also found a code that works as my goal would be`, when you want to reduce the process cost of your bottom script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function CopyData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Auto");
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
  var rg1 = sh1.getRange("A2:M2000");
  var vA = rg1.getValues().filter(r => r[5]);
  sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vA.length, vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
}
```

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I couldn't imagine your Spreadsheet from your question. So, I proposed a modified script by guessing your bottom script works while the process cost is high. If that was not the direct solution to your issue, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what was going on my mind. Now the script works way faster and ignores empty cells with formula in them. Thank you for explaining what is going on, it helps to learn the process of script making :)

Comment: Hello, I think something went wrong. Script was working just fine all the time and today when i tried to change range from M2000, to M10000 I received error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') directin to part: "vA[0].length"

Why would that happen if I may know and what would be a solution to that?

Comment: @Michał Dziedzic About your new question, I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: No problem at all, gonna make a new question in a minute. Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind, seems like the problem was not in a script. It seems there was not enough data to copy? Once I filled in everything correctly it worked again. Sorry for trouble. Problem fixed.

Comment: @Michał Dziedzic Thank you for replying. I'm glad your new question was resolved.